# Push package to Octopus Deploy fail from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, octopus-deploy, octopus

My VSTS build is getting successful and artifact is also creating in .nupgk format.
but when I create a release and hook it with my Octopus deploy cloud instance through service connection and using "Push package to Octopus" , it's  throwing an error (Screen attached)

Please Help
[image: problem]
[image: Built]
[image: release]`Probelm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get this error if the url to the server, in your Service Connection, isn't the root url for your Octopus instance. The value you're using is cut off in the screenshot, does it include a path? If so, removing the path should resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Shannon, I modify the path and remove /app#/ and it worked. Thanks again for the help !!